# Mvc overwrites my Id's in hidden fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We use MVC 4  in combination with Entity Framework.
I have an persistent Entity base-class, this class defines that all Entities have an in code generated `GUID Id`:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   ;...
}
```

And the following concrete classes:

```
public class Person : Entity
{
   public List<Position> Positions{get;set;}
   ;...
}

public class Position : Entity
{
   ;...
   public Guid Person{get; set;}
   public Guid PersonId{get; set;} //recently added because of other EF issues :-(
}
```

In the view for Position we tried several things but MVC quite persistently tries to
replace "Id" with "PersonId":

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)  
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PersonId)
```

If we just have an Id hidden field it is overwritten with PersonId when rendering the view
If we make it an "PositionId" it is preserved and returned in the FormValue Collection
(Request["PositionId"] yields the correct value) but the MVC  ModelBinder buggers things up again:

```
public ActionResult Edit (Postion model)
{
    // model.Id = Guid.Parse(Request["PositionId"]);
    ...
    bool isFoiledAganin = modelId.Equals(model.PersonId); // true 
}
```

Only uncommenting the `model.Id` assignment fixes things.
*My guess is that the ModelBinder losses it's way when it finds something with "id" in the class, without considering inherited fields.* **Is there a way to put her straight?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the answers given so far explain what is happening or address the issue. For now we implement the hack:
In the view we place the Id in a hidden field which we explicitly name Id:

```
@Html.Hidden("PositionId", Model.Id);
```

This makes sure the correct id is placed in the HTML by the View, and it will be returned in the FormValueCollection.

The first action of the controller method is to retrieve that value and restore it to the model:

```
model.Id = Guid.Parse(Request["PositionId"]);
```

It sucks, but it beats the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand the question, but why don't you use the strongly-typed variant `HiddenFor`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Person.Id);
```

You can get the values in the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit (Postion model)
{
    Guid positionId = model.Id;
    Guid personId = model.Person.Id;
}
```

**Update:**

You should not use domain (entity) models in your views, create ViewModels in stead:

```
public class PositionModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit (int positionId)
{
    // Get position from db.
    Position position = db.Positions.Find(positionId);

    // Map it to a ViewModel.
    PositionModel positionModel = new PositionModel
                                      {
                                        Id = position.Id,
                                        PersonId position.Person.Id
                                      };

    return View(positionModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (Postion model)
{
    Guid positionId = model.Id;
    Guid personId = model.PersonId;
}
```

Your view will look like this:

```
@model PositionModel;

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonId);
```

Comment: Code is cleaner, but result is the same: The Position model has the Id of the Person, not his "own" Id set when the position was created. I.e. the modelbinder still assigns the PersonId from the view to the Id property of position.

Comment: @k.c. how about using ViewModels in stead of domain models in your view? I've updated my answer with a small example.

Comment: To the MVC purist that may be the correct way of doing things, personally I don't want to add the overhead of moving each entity field to it's corresponding viewmodel field one on one... Still thanks for working with me on this one ;-)

Comment: @k.c. yeah well, but using domain models in your view causes problems like this.. I rarely have a view model which is a exact copy of the domain model. As you can see, the one I proposed is also different then your domain model. The overhead is definitely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have given the name PersonID instead of id. So change the name.

`@Html.Hidden("PersonId", Model.Person.Id)`  **to**  `@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Person.Id)`

Comment: No, there is Position.Id (inherited from Entity) which is the primary key of position, and there is a foreignkey navigation property Position.PersonId. Both are needed. And I need the model binder to assign each one, not PersonId to both PositionId and Id

Comment: Then use @Html.HiddenFor and bind it with Id

Comment: What do you mean with "and bind with id" that is what i'm trying to do, the question is how

Comment: What error are you getting if you do @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Person.Id); check your html using ctrl + u and paste it here the html tag for this hidden variable.

Comment: It doesn't give an error, it contains the correct value. The wrong value is placed in the Id field, it contains the value of model.Person.Id not model.Id

Comment: What is your model? Person or what?

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Person_Id" name="Person.Id" type="hidden" value="a09a16d6-a54d-46db-bf62-ee9a71453424"> <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="a09a16d6-a54d-46db-bf62-ee9a71453424">

Comment: Instead of Person.Id, you want Id. Right?

Comment: Note: both guid are the same in the html, while the should be two different ones.

Comment: Could you please try to make non abstract Entity class and check the result.

Comment: If I make Entity a concrete class, EF will generate a table for it. It will hurt performance as ALL entities will be placed in that table and data will always need a join on that table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Person.Id);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fix the problem... Actually it is worse after the rendering of the view the "Id" hidden field has the value of model.Person.Id not it's assigned value. Also the fix "// model.Id = Guid.Parse(Request["PositionId"]);" doesn't work then.